# Kill screen session after sending commands to it

Tags: linux, bash, session, scripting, expect

Hi I have the following script setup and would like the screen session to be killed after running the script passed in the final command.

```
testCommand="$testCommand; exec bash"
read -sp $user'@example.com password: ' password
screen  -d -m -S dart bash -c "ssh example.com";
sleep 1
screen -S dart -p0 -X stuff "$password
"
sleep 1
screen -S dart -p0 -X stuff "cd $localListDir
"
sleep 1
screen -S dart -p0 -X stuff "$testCommand
"
```

Note I cannot set up ssh keys for the ssh connection so sending the password like this is the only option.

The last `"screen -S dart -p0 -X stuff "$testCommand"` runs a script on the ssh connection. This script could run for minuets or for hours. After this script is finished running i would like the screen session to end so the user of the script does not need to kill it themselves.

I believe it has something to do with the `"; exec bash"` at then end of testCommand but without this the script would hang on a long wait until you attached to the screen.

Thanks

**Edit**

Thanks for the quick replies.

So after looking at expect a bit I have added the following to my script

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn ssh example.com
expect "password: "
send "$password\r"
expect "> "
send "cd $localListDir\r"
expect "> "
send "$testCommand\r"
expect "> "
EOF
```

Is there a way to get the testCommand script to run in the background? so the user doesn't see any of the output.
And is there a way to get expect to expect the next line rather than having the `"> "` as this could be different for others.
Thanks again

Comment: try using `expect` instead, it was designed for this.

Comment: Other options except this approach would include writing an `expect` script or getting `sshpass` and using that to invoke your `ssh` session